# Azure Bot Function - namespace/dependency error

Tags: c#, azure, bots, botframework, botconnector

I've created a simple Azure Bot Function that works fine when ran in Azure. I have installed the required SDK's but when I download/copy the solution locally (Windows 10 using VS 2017) and then run `"dotnet restore"` followed by `"debughost.cmd"` I get the following error:

> Function compilation error ... error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Bot' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

How do I manage the dependencies? The solution has no "References" folder and *"Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..."* is grayed out.

Is this a VS 2017 problem? I don't have VS 2015 currently installed.

Thanks, TK

Answer (score 4):

I got probably the same issue and managed to fix it by adding the reference to Bot Connector in the **project.json**. You need to do another `dotnet restore` after.

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure": "3.2.1",
        "Microsoft.Bot.Connector": "1.1.0"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Thanks, 
Dini